# Serializing/parsing multiple objects in one file in Qt C++

Tags: c++, json, qt

I need to serialize and parse multiple objects from my project, in order to save/load them when needed.

My objects will have exactly the same components : a QString *name*, an integer *id*, a QString *description*, and two integer *x*, *y*.
I'll need something like this :

```
{"name":"toto", "id":"42", "description":"tata", "x":"20", "y":"50"}
```

So I'll build my QJsonObject like this :

```
QJsonObject json;
json["id"] = object_to_serialize.get_id();
json["name"] = object_to_serialize.get_name();
json["description"] = object_to_serialize.get_description();
json["x"] = object_to_serialize.get_x();
json["y"] = object_to_serialize.get_y();
QJsonDocument filedoc(json);
file.write(filedoc.toJson);`
```

And in the file it will appear like this :

```
{"name":"toto", "id":"42", "description":"tata", "x":"20", "y":"50"}
{"name":"toto2", "id":"44", "description":"tata2", "x":"25", "y":"547"}  
{"name":"toto3", "id":"46", "description":"tata3", "x":"21", "y":"580"}
```

My serialiser will take in parameter the object, the savefile name, and transform the object into a QJsonObject. It will need then to read the file to check if an object with the same *id* is here. If it is here, it will need to replace it, and if it is not, it will append it.

I'm a little lost between my serialization options and how to read it ;

Should I make a QJsonArray with multiple QJsonObject inside or QJsonObject with QJsonArrays ?

When I read it, I will need to check for the id ; but will a

```
foreach(object.value["id"] == 42)
  //create the QJsonObject from the one with 42 and change it with the new data
```

will do to parse the object and not all of them ? Is there a better way ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Your objective in particular is to save the data in a file where each line is a json and then to be able to read it obtaining the same object, am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are, and find it fairly easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an array of json object, each of them having an ID so you can parse the relevant ones.

Although you could also parse all of them and add them in a map, as long as you don't have very heavy files it should be fine.

```
void parseJson(const QString &data)
{
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());

    if (doc.isNull())
    {
        war("invalid json document");
        return;
    }


    QJsonArray jsonArray = doc.array();
    foreach (const QJsonValue & value, jsonArray) {
        QJsonObject obj = value.toObject();
        if (obj.contains("id"))
        {
            if (obj["id"].toInt() == yourId) parseObject(obj);
        }
    }
}


void parseObject(const QJsonObject &obj)
{
    if (obj.contains("valueA")) valueA = obj["valueA"].toDouble();
    if (obj.contains("valueB")) valueB = obj["valueB"].toDouble();
}
```

This will work just fine if your file is not too big

---

#### Bigger Files

Now if you have very large file, it might be an issue to load it all in memory and parse it.

Since your structure is always the same and quite simple, JSON might not be the best choice, one more efficient method would be to do your own parser (or use probably some existing ones) that could read the file and process it as a stream.

---

Another method, would be to have one JSON entry per line preceded by an ID with a fixed number of digit. Load this in a QHash lookup and then only read id of interest from the file and only parse a small section.

```
// This code is not tested and is just to show the principle.
#define IDSIZE 5
QHash<int64, int64> m_lookup; // has to be global var

// For very large file, this might take some time and can be done on a separate thread.
// it needs to be done only once at startup (given the file is not modified externally)
void createLookup(const QString &fileName)
{
    QFile inputFile(fileName);
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
          int position = in.pos(); // store the position in the file
          QString line = in.readLine();
          int id = line.mid(0,IDSIZE).toInt(); // 5 digit id (like 00001, 00002, etc...
          m_lookup[id] = position + IDSIZE;
       }
       inputFile.close();
    }
}

QString getEntry(const QString &fileName, int64 id)
{
     if (m_lookup.contains(id))
     {
        QFile inputFile(fileName);
        if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
            inputFile.seek(m_lookup[id]);
            QString data = inputFile.readLine();
            inputFile.close();
            return data;
        } else {
            return QString(); // or handle error
        }
     } else {
        return QString(); // or handle error
     }
}

// use example
QString data = getEntry(id);
if (data.length() > 0)
{
    QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data.toUtf8());
    if (!doc.isNull())
    {
        // assign your variables
    }
}
```

and your data file looking like this:

```
00042{"name":"toto", "id":"42", "description":"tata", "x":"20", "y":"50"}
00044{"name":"toto2", "id":"44", "description":"tata2", "x":"25", "y":"547"}  
00046{"name":"toto3", "id":"46", "description":"tata3", "x":"21", "y":"580"}
```

The advantage of this method, it will only read the entry of interest, and avoid having to load MB or GB of data in memory just to get a specific entry.

This could further be improved with a lookup table stored at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Do you have a kind of method to serialize these object effectively ; I mean, I need sometime to take one of these items and alter it (change its name, its description... Can I use your parse method to change it directly in the JsonArray and to rewrite the entire file ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. with the last method, you can take one item, modify it and rewrite it without having to change the rest of the file. (The system will still have to modify the file if the length of your entry is different in which case you could use padding).